# how to use data output from reactive function as condition in conditional pannel

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am trying to read data and if the data has observation , the further UI has to expand. But the conditional Pannel is not working .

Here is the part of the UI and server code.

**UI Code:**

[image]

```
tabPanel("DMC 1.1", fluid = TRUE, useShinyjs(),
         column(width=12,wellPanel(div(style = 'height:120px;',
                              fluidRow(column(width=9,style = "font-size: 12px;",fileInput("analysis_data2", label = "Import data", accept = c(".csv",".sas7bdat",".xls",".xpt"))))
                              )),

 conditionalPanel(condition = "output.dataUpload",  wellPanel(fluidRow(

column(width=5,textInput("subset","Subsettign Condition",value="")),

column(width=5,textInput("byvar","By Variable",value="")),

column(width=5,textInput("subgrp","SubGroup Variable",value="")),

column(width=5,textInput("trtvar","Treatment Variable",value="")),

column(width=5,textInput("xaxisvar","X Axis Variable",value="")),

column(width=5,textInput("yaxisvar","Y Axis Variable",value=""))
                                               )))
                              )
                )
```

**Server Code:**

```
  #################Tab 2 - DMC 2.0#########################
  

analysis_d <- reactive({data_read(datain=input$analysis_data2)})
  
output$dataUpload <- reactive({return(!is.null(isolate(analysis_d())))})
  
outputOptions(output, 'dataUpload', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  That said, I'd approach this problem differently and use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` rather than `conditionalPanel`, the reason being that this removes the intermediate dependency on Javascript, which I find flaky.  Also, note that a shiny UI is constrained to have a total column width of 12.  You have a total width of 30.  This may lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This app will make an additional text input files available in the UI if the uploaded csv file contains at least one row:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "File"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.available",
    textInput("additional_input", "additional input")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive(read.csv(input$file$datapath))

  output$available <- reactive(nrow(data()) >= 1)
  outputOptions(output, "available", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```